# How to set breakpoint to server bundled by webpack

Tags: node.js, debugging, webpack, webstorm, package.json

The project I'm working on has Redis on port 6379 and the node server on port 5000. I'm running the server by running `npm run server`
My package.json script is the following:

```
webpack --watch --progress --config ./build/server/webpack.dev.js
```

I'm unable to attach a debugger when I add a configuration for `Attach to Node.js/Chrome` on port 5000 and click the bug icon in WebStorm.

I get `invalid response from the remote host`

Am I supposed to patch an `--inspect` option to my package JSON script?

EDIT: I passed inspect down to nodemon. I'm able to attach to the debugger now, but my breakpoints arent suspending. The webpack configs are below:

```
const commonWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.common')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const NodemonPlugin = require('nodemon-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(commonWebpackConfig, {
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new NodemonPlugin({
        nodeArgs: [ '--inspect'],
        script: './dist/server.js'
    })
  ]
})


const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'server', 'app.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [
              ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {'loose': false}]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I found the breakpoint mapping issue. I needed to add the following:

`devtool: "eval-source-map",`

EDIT:

I don't think the breakpoints are fully working for blocsk of code that has async/await though

Comment: you need passing `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` to node.js when starting your application to be able to attach a debugger to it. So yes - you have to modify your npm script accordingly

Comment: Would i add ` && node --inspect-brk` to the the npm script? I'm a new hire and the current dev has been using console logging to debug. He's not sure how to set it up. I think having breakpoints would greatly help us. From what I understand, the webpack.dev is just the webpack config. I'd have to find where the dis folder is right?

Comment: `webpack --watch --progress --config ./build/server/webpack.dev.js` doesn't normally start the app, it builds the application; adding  `&& node --inspect-brk` won't work. You need to find the actual command that starts your application and modify it, adding the `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` to node.js args

Comment: So I found out we're using nodemon-webpack-plugin so I passed down `nodeArgs: [ '--inspect']` as an option and then was able to attach a debugger to port 9229.

However, my breakpoints aren't being hit. They get a check mark in webstorm which means its found. Not sure if its a mapping issue? Im testing the breakpoint in an area of the code where I know for a fact gets hit.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work. We were using nodemon-webpack-plugin, so I needed to pass in nodeArgs like Lena said. I passed it `--inspect` which by default is port 9229.

I then had to add `devtools: "eval-source-map` So that my breakpoints had the right mapping.

EDIT:

I don't think the breakpoints are fully working for blocsk of code that has async/await though